# Regex to match a set of characters but only if particular characters are not grouped

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, preg-split

This is a tricky one, I have a string:

```
This is some text with a {%TAG IN IT%} and some more text then {%ANOTHER TAG%} with some more text at the end.
```

I have a regex to match the tags:

```
({%\w+[\w =!:;,\.\$%"'#\?\-\+\{}]*%})
```

Which will match a starting tag with any alphanumeric character followed by any number of other ansi characters (sample set specified in the regex above).

However (in PHP using **"preg_match_all"** and **"preg_split"** at least) the fact that the set contains both the percent (%) and the curly braces ({}) means that the regex matches too much if there are two tags on the same line.

e.g, in the example given, the following is matched:

```
{%TAG IN IT%} and some more text then {%ANOTHER TAG%}
```

As you can see, the %}...{% were matched. So, what I need is to allow the **"%"** but NOT when followed by **"}"**

I've tried non-reedy matching, and negative lookahead, but the negative lookahead won't work in a character set (i.e. everything in the [\w...]* set).

I'm stuck!

Comment: So both `%` and `}` may appear as a valid tag value?

Comment: % and } may both appear as valid characters in a tag (json values can be stored in them) However, %} cannot be together... that is the end of the tag :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight modification of your regexp works(Just add the question mark to make it non-greedy)-

```
<?php
    $input = "This is some text with a {%TAG % }IT%%} and some more text then {%ANOTHER TAG%} with some more text at the end.";
    $regexp = "/{%\w+[\w =!:;,\.\$%\"'#\?\-\+\{}]*?%}/";
    //                                            ^ Notice this
    if(preg_match_all($regexp, $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
        foreach($matches as $match) {
            var_dump($match);
            echo "\r\n";
        }
        unset($match);
    }
    /*
        Outputs:
        array
          0 => string '{%TAG % }IT%%}' (length=14)
        array
          0 => string '{%ANOTHER TAG%}' (length=15)
    */
?>
```

Comment: Excellent - thanks for the quick and simple response!. FYI the full regex is a fair bit more complicated... (117 characters long) but in the end, the non-greedy specifier did actually work!

Answer (score 1):

You could use alternation to achieve this:

```
/\{%(?:[^%]|%(?!}))*%\}/
```

It matches either characters that aren't `%` or those that aren't followed by `}` (using a look-ahead [assertion](http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)).

```
$str = 'This is some text with a {%tag with % and } inside%} and some more text then {%ANOTHER TAG%} with some more text at the end.';

$pattern = '/\{%(?:[^%]|%(?!}))*%\}/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {%tag with % and } inside%}
    [1] => {%ANOTHER TAG%}
)
```

Comment: Yes but if `%` is at the last position in the substring the pattern will match %% and continue to the next `%}` or fail.

Comment: Yes that is almost what I need, although "any characters" aren't allowed. Only characters specified in the set... :-(

Comment: When working with the matches, you can always choose to ignore entries that aren't valid for whatever reason.